# How do I mount NETGEAR ReadyShare network folder in a Debian 11 LXC hosted within Proxmox VE?

Tags: debian, mount, network-shares, samba, cifs

My router has some network attached storage capabilities and it shares the files via a UNC path (I assume this is a SAMBA share). The UNC path defined by the router is `//routershare/media/`

I'm able to mount this as a network drive in Windows 11 (standalone instance, not Proxmox VM), as well as access it via the UNC path. I'm struggling to mount it in a LXC container (hosted in Proxmox VE) though.

All the documentation I've read said it should be as simple as creating a new directory to mount to and running the command:

```
mount -t cifs -o //routershare/media /mnt/media
```

That command throws the following error:

> mount error: could not resolve address for routershare: Unknown error

Here is the setup of the routershare (It's a NETGEAR R6700v3 router):

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried additional variations such as adding the workgroup and security options, but got the same error.

```
mount -t cifs -o sec=none,workgroup=Workgroup //routershare/media /mnt/media
```

I also tried using the ip address of the router instead of the share:

```
mount -t cifs -o workgroup=Workgroup //192.168.1.1/media /mnt/media
```

This prompts me for a password - There is no password on the share so I just hit enter. The following error occurs:

> mount error(1): Operation not permitted Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

I tried setting the security to none and I don't get the password promt this time, but I do get the same operation not permitted error:

```
mount -t cifs -o sec=none,workgroup=Workgroup //192.168.1.1/media /mnt/media
```

I'm a bit new to Linux and I'm probably missing something obvious, any next troubleshooting tips or documentation that I should be looking at would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the password prompt you get isn't for your account's admin password on your Linux machine? mounting to /mnt/media will require sudo/admin access.

Try placing sudo in front of your last two commands where you are getting the Operation not permitted error.

Comment: I'm actually logged in as the root user (sudo isn't recognized as a command). The password prompt that I get seems to be for the share:
`root@docker:/# mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/media /mnt/media
Password for root@//192.168.1.1/media: 
mount error(1): Operation not permitted
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)`


If I edit the command with the option sec=none I don't get the password prompt, but it gives the same operation not permitted error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://pve.proxmox.com/pve-docs-6/chapter-pct.html#_fuse_mounts).

> Because of existing issues in the Linux kernel’s freezer subsystem the usage of FUSE mounts inside a container is strongly advised against, as containers need to be frozen for suspend or snapshot mode backups. If FUSE mounts cannot be replaced by other mounting mechanisms or storage technologies, it is possible to establish the FUSE mount on the Proxmox host and use a bind mount point to make it accessible inside the container.

For anyone else looking for a step by step tutorial on how to setup network shares with Proxmox LXC containers, this is the guide I used: https://www.thushanfernando.com/notes/proxmox-cifs-setup/

Answer (score 0):

Everything is as mentioned in other answers but you need to use the address like so:

`//readyshare.routerlogin.net/S_Drive` (assuming S_Drive is what it is named in your setup)

So the full command after creating the directory to mount would be:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //readyshare.routerlogin.net/S_Drive /mnt/s_drive -o guest
```